# Load css file using absolute path for my component?

Tags: jdocument, jhtml

My site has configured multilanguage, i develop now a small component and need physical path of my component, and if i use *JPATH_COMPONENT_ADMINISTRATOR* then i get still

**http://example.com.com/LANGUAGE_STRING/administrator/components/com_mycomponent...**

How can I get really physical path? I tested also most of [this](http://docs.joomla.org/Constants) constants, but no one works correctly, i need it exactly for external css file:

```
$doc = JFactory::getDocument();
$doc->addStyleSheet(JPATH_COMPONENT_ADMINISTRATOR . '/assets/css/component_style.css');
```

Comment: For an external CSS file, why not simply use the domain name? Using absolute paths for importing assets is not a good idea

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To load CSS and Javascript files, you want to use `JUri::base()` instead of JPATH_COMPONENT_ADMINISTRATOR.

Also have a look at a more advanced loading mechanism, JHtml.

[Adding JavaScript and CSS to the page](http://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Adding_JavaScript_and_CSS_to_the_page)